# Run and Execute a Program Using A Batch File

Tags: batch-file, echo, batch-processing

I have this batch script that helps me download and run my programme automatically. But here is the issue I am having: This makes its own directory, but the downloaded programme does not store anything inside.

Question: How do I make this programme store inside the already-created directory?

```
md "7Zip"
echo "downloading 7Zip"
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe -Outfile 7Zip"

start 7Zip

echo "Done"
cls
exit
```

Getting the downloaded file to save and run inside the created directory has been the major issue. I am looking for solutions to this problem.

Comment: `-Outfile` is for the file you want to output too, in this case you're saving the file as `7zip` instead. However this will then fail, because there exists a folder with that name already, you need to specify the directory and file, i.e `powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe -Outfile .\7Zip\7z2201-x64.exe"`

Comment: I keep having issues after finished running the program. It says "Windows can not find ..." how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should read `Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Parameter OutFile` in PowerShell - you would then know what `OutFile` specifies. That said, you can probably do this without invoking PowerShell at all - via `curl`:

```
set directory=7zip

:: Create a directory first, silencing errors
mkdir "%directory%" >nul 2>&1

:: If %directory% exists AND is a directory, execute the command
if exist "%directory%\*" (
    curl -O --output-dir "%directory%" "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe"
)
```

Just make sure you:

- check that a directory exists (and is a directory) before writing to it
- don't mix output file and directory for `curl` - either provide full path via `--output` or do as above

Comment: The program runs perfectly and stores in the give folder, but the issue is the program does not run automatically on its own. I want a situation that the program can start running after it has finished downloading.

Comment: With `curl -O` the output file will be named as the remore file, so you could do `curl -O --output-dir "%directory%" "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe" && 7z2201-x64.exe`. `&&` means "if the previous command succeeded", i.e. `curl`.